# Unittest for setup.py

Tags: python, python-unittest

I've got the following Python application:

```
.
├── application
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── code
│   │   ├── ...
│   └── test
│       ├── ...
└── setup.py
```

The `setup.py` can be used to install `application`. Also, the `setup.py` can be used to run the unittests, which are in `application/test`

Now, I want to create a unittest in `application/test` that tries to install the application, and fails if this cannot be installed.

My code for such an unittest would be:

```
import unittest
import os


class TestInstallation(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_installation(self):
        os.system('virtualenv --python=python3 ENV')
        os.system('source ENV/bin/activate')

        # install application
        os.system('python setup.py install')
        self.assertTrue('application' in os.system('pip list'))

        os.system('deactivate')
        os.system('rm -rf ENV')
```

However, this doesn't work, since each command is executed separately. (i.e. after you execute the command to start the virtual-environment, you immediately exit this environment).

This leads to the question what is a good alternative to test whether the application can be installed successfully. Can this be done in Python, or only using shell commands?

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

The activation of a venv is nothing more than adapting of `PATH` and `PYTHONHOME` in the shell so you use the correct executables from this venv. If you explicitly specify the path to executables, you don't need to run `ENV/bin/activate`. For example, the command sequence

```
$ virtualenv ENV --python=python3
$ source ENV/bin/activate
$ python setup.py install
$ pip list
$ deactivate
```

is equivalent to the sequence

```
$ virtualenv ENV --python=python3
$ ENV/bin/python setup.py install
$ ENV/bin/pip list
```

You can use that in your test. Additionally, I would:

- move the creation and deletion of `ENV` in the test class setup/teardown so the actual test has less noise. Also, `tearDown` will ensure that your venv is deleted even if `test_installation` should fail;
- replace `os.system` usage with `subprocess` as it returns a much nicer result object to check against;
- run the commands with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to capture the printed lines (also, so they won't clutter the test output);
- use `pip list --format=freeze` so you can check package name and version.

However, this is all optional and you don't have to follow this example.

This is how I would adapt the test:

```
import shutil
import subprocess
import unittest


class TestInstallation(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        subprocess.run(['virtualenv', 'ENV', '--python=python3'], 
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.python = 'ENV/bin/python3'
        self.pip = 'ENV/bin/pip3'

    def tearDown(self):
        shutil.rmtree('ENV')

    def test_installation(self):
        subprocess.run([self.python, 'setup.py', 'install'], 
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        # check the installation succeeded (process exited with a 0)
        self.assertEqual(result.returncode, 0)

        result = subprocess.run([self.pip, 'list', '--format=freeze'],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                universal_newlines=True)
        self.assertIn('application==0.1', result.stdout.split())
```